# document.body.appendChild before page load

Tags: javascript

Will it cause any issue if i include an iframe element before page load event

Comment: it might...can you show us some code? :D

Comment: the script to include iframe element is in the body tag. What would be the best way to add it to page as soon as possible.

Comment: Uh... maybe you could accept some answers on your other questions? Also, just try it.  We're not stopping you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It fails in IE showing an alert box. Keep such type of code in scriptlet with defer attribute.